# How to write rspec get statements for customized routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have defined a user resource, and each user has several items. Now I want to add a route for `/user/:id/items(.:format)`, instead of defining items as nested resource, I use member route:

```
resources :user do
  member do
    match "/items" => "items#index", :via => [:get]
  end
end
```

The problem is when I try to write rspec for the controller, I don't know what action should I use to access `items#index`. I tried

```
describe ItemsController do
  it "denies access to item index without login" do
    sign_out @user
    get "index", :user_id => @user.id, :format => :json
    response.code.should == "401"
  end
  # ...
end
```

But after executing rake spec:controllers it says

```
Failure/Error: get "index", :user_id => @user.id, :format => :json
ActionController::RoutingError:
  No route matches {:user_id=>"1", :format=>"json", :controller=>"items"}
```

I am using Rails 3.1. How can I use rspec to test this member route? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure it needs to be:

```
get :index, :id => @user.id, :format => :json
```

You need to pass `:id`, not `:user_id`